# Java - What's wrong with my applet's cookies code?

Tags: java, cookies, applet

Here's what I have:

```
// save the game as a browser cookie
public void savecookie(){
    try{
        CookieManager manager=new CookieManager();
        CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
        CookieStore store=manager.getCookieStore();
        HttpCookie cookie=new HttpCookie("JujuSaveData",tocookie());
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setVersion(0);
        cookie.setSecure(false);
        cookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365*100);
        cookie.setComment("Juju save data");
        URL url=new URL("http://www.pineapplemachine.com");
        store.add(url.toURI(),cookie);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
// load the game from a cookie
public void loadcookie(){
    try{
        CookieManager manager=new CookieManager();
        manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
        URL url=new URL("http://www.pineapplemachine.com");
        URLConnection connection=url.openConnection();
        connection.getContent();
        CookieStore store=manager.getCookieStore();
        List<HttpCookie> cookies=store.getCookies();
        for(HttpCookie cookie:cookies){
            if(cookie.getName().equals("JujuSaveData")){
                fromcookie(cookie.getValue());
                break;
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The applet itself is here: http://pineapplemachine.com/juju/juju.html

It's intended to save the game state as a cookie and load it later. That doesn't happen. I'm using chrome, and when I search for the cookie that should have been saved none comes up.

What have I got wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok for me, I think your problem is that your applet not accomplish security requirements. According to [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/accessingCookies.html): To access cookies, you must sign your applet JAR file and request permission to run outside of the security sandbox.

Hope this helps,